# How to remove '|' from json export in splunk?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, splunk

So I am trying to export through python splunk queries to elasticsearch. I am using the json.dump() feature in python which is working and converting exactly like SPLUNK Web's convert feature. My issue with it though is that it's giving me one field, named _RAW, with pipes '|' information so elastic search doesn't see the individual fields yet clumps it all together like so:

```
Data| nameId="123123" | exampleID='1234123' | fieldName="Example" ....etc
```

I want to be able to have a "data" field or a "fieldName" field not all of that clumped into one big field named "raw"

Answer (score 2):

To remove the `_raw` field, you can use `| fields - _raw` at the end of your search.

You may need to post your code if that doesn't help, as we may need more context

Answer (score 0):

I got what I needed from appending `| Fields *` to the end of my query. I was running a python script that queried splunk but it was running in fast mode not verbose, so the fields that I needed where in a _raw format and not individually displayed like in verbose.